# How to implement NEAT into a pygame?

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm fairly new to StackOverflow, so please forgive me if this is in the wrong section, or if I'm not supplying enough information.

I've been inspired by videos on the internet that use genetic algorithms with neural networks using the NEAT algorithm. I've downloaded the XOR example from the neat-python docs and understood most of its code, as well as ran it myself and experimenting with it. However, I would like to learn how I would implement this into a simple Flappy Bird styled game using Python 2.7 and pygame, as I think that would be the easiest to do. All I need is information to jump-start me and take off. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Generally you need to provide some code to show what you've attempted when asking questions. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't really tried anything because I do not know where to start. :(

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv6UVOQ0F44